# Android Studio: No build variant found for ':expo'. error

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo, variant

I Encountered a error saying No variants found for ':expo'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists.

I Already download all the SDK's Clear the Project multi times but nothing work

Here is the build.gradle code

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.301'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```